# check for empty radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I want to check if the user selects a radio button. I have coded this:

**HTML**

```
<form action="myServlet" method="post">
        <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-5" name="ratingInput1" value="5">
        <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-4" name="ratingInput1" value="4">
        <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-3" name="ratingInput1" value="4">        
        //etc
<button type="submit" class="myButton" onclick="sendSuccess()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
   function sendSuccess(){

        var len = document.formRate.ratingInput1.length;
        var flag;

        for(i=0; i<len; i++){
            if (document.formRate.ratingInput[i].checked){
                flag = true;
            }
            else{
                flag = false;
                break;
            }   
        }

        if(flag === false){
            console.log('noooooo');
            return false;
        }else{
            console.log('yesssss');
        }
    }
```

But its not working.

Comment: I don't really follow what you're trying to achieve, do you want a console.log once a radio button is check, or do you want it when the button is clicked?

Comment: i just want to know, if the user doesn't select anything.

Comment: You also need to return false or preventDefault in the function, otherwise form will continue submission

Comment: formRate: just forgot to take it off..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/cXPYQ/

Hope this fit your needs `:)`
**Code**

```
  $("form").submit(function () {
    var flag = true;
    $(':radio').each(function () {
        name = $(this).attr('name');
        if (flag && !$(':radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length) {
            alert(name + ' group not checked');
            flag = false;
        }
    });
    return flag;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `jQuery` using [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find radio button with same name and `:checked` to get only checked elements. You can use `length` to check if you get any checked radio button or not. The `length` will be zero of none of `radio` button is checked and will be greater then zero if one or more radio button is checked.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x7cQt/)**

```
if($('[name=ratingInput1]:checked').length)
     console.log('Yes');
else
     console.log('No');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<form name="formRate" action="myServlet" method="post">
    <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-5" name="ratingInput1" value="5">
    <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-4" name="ratingInput1" value="4">
    <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-3" name="ratingInput1" value="4">        
    <button type="submit" class="myButton" onclick="return sendSuccess();">Submit</button>
</form>

function sendSuccess(){

var flag = false;

var len = $('input:radio[name="ratingInput1"]:checked').size();

    if(len == 0){
        console.log('noooooo');
        flag = false;
    }else{
        console.log('yesssss');
        flag = true;
    }
return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple form with radio buttons, so all you need is give the form a name formRate, and no need for jQuery, the following will work

HTML

```
<form name="formRate" action="myServlet" method="post">
    <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-5" name="ratingInput1" value="5">
    <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-4" name="ratingInput1" value="4">
    <input type="radio" id="rating-input-1-3" name="ratingInput1" value="4">        
    <button type="submit" class="myButton" onclick="return sendSuccess();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function sendSuccess() {
rating = document.forms["formname"]["ratingInput1"].value;
if(rating > 0){
    console.log(rating);
 }
 else {
    console.log('No rating');
 }
 return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

var flag = $('[name="ratingInput1"]').is(':checked');

will return false if no radio with that name is chosen.